# "opencv_java" library missing for robot framework Sikuli library installation in Red Hat 7

Tags: opencv, robotframework, sikuli

I'm trying to install Robot Framework Sikuli libary on Red Hat 7 server. Installation of library was successful using `pip`, however while executing scripts `Sikuli` fails with following java error:

```
[error] RunTimeAPI: loadLib: opencv_java not usable:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java in java.library.path
```

I have tried to installed OpenCV library for Red Hat but it did not resolve the issue. Unable to find package that provides `opencv_java` file. Could you please help to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Java is try to look for the library file `libopencv_java.so` but the library is named with version no. as `libopencv_java<version>.so`. Creating a symbolic link to the file with name `libopencv_java.so` should fix the issue. Here's an example for Debian 9.

```
cd /usr/lib/jni
ln -s libopencv_java249.so libopencv_java.so
```